# How to check if NS records are correct?

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

I am trying to set up Iodine *(probably not that important)* and to get it running I need to create a NS record on my domain and run a service on port 53 on my server.

Let's say I own "**domain.com.**" and a VPS with public ip **1.2.3.4**. The zone file has been preset by my registrar to have one A record (**@ A 1.2.3.4**) and two NS records (**@ NS ns01.domaincontrol.com**, **@ NS ns02.domaincontrol.com**)

I would go to zone file settings and create:

> tunnel A 1.2.3.4

Then:

> tunnelzone NS tunnel.domain.com

And save the zone file.
Now if I:

> ping anythingatall.tunnelzone.domain.com

**QUESTIONS:**
The resolver should ultimately querry machine at IP 1.2.3.4, correct?

Could I then, in theory, create "**pipezone NS somewhere.else.org**" in zone file on my VPS server, and have DNS on somewhere.else.org take care of its own subdomains?

Also, if I am right, is there a reason for the zone file changes, that have to do with NS type records, to be extremely slow to get in "production"?

*Thanks a lot to anyone who will help me clear this out in my head, I'd like to understand the whole networking thing a lot more.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are right about how delegation works, but it looks like your zone syntax might be messing up your delegation.  If you're using something with a bind-like zone file syntax, then you're creating your NS record delegations as relative, which would cause them to break.

```
; This line:
tunnelzone IN NS tunnel.domain.com
; is equivalent to:
tunnelzone IN NS tunnel.domain.com.domain.com.
;
```

That's not what you want.  Instead, you probably want:

```
; This line:
tunnelzone IN NS tunnel
; is equivalent to:
tunnelzone IN NS tunnel.domain.com.
;
; And for your other delegation, you'll want absolute as well:
pipezone IN NS somewhere.else.org.
```

Can you clarify what symptoms you're seeing?  Query for a record of type `NS` at `tunnelzone.domain.com`; what response do you get?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this cleared think up for me a lot. It did work in the end, just had to wait a bit longer and play with dig a bit.
But somehow your syntax now seems more logical, I will try if it works too. (GoDaddy is hosting my domain :( so I am not too sure about which DNS server they use.)

Comment: Ahh gotcha, they probably take care of the trailing dots for you.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a reason for the zone file changes, that have to do with NS type records, to be extremely slow to get in "production"?

Check times data in SOA RR for your parent zone (and decrease, maybe)

Comment: I only have access to some sort of domain control web ui from GoDaddy, I don't think I would be able to do that. The only "time" I have access to is TTL, which I always set to 1/2 hour.